# How do I test long memory in ARFIMA?

Tags: long-range-dependence, arfima

I've been wondering about measuring long-term memory in ARFIMA models - should I use ACF/PACF for it? Or maybe there are some different methods - and then is there anything I didn't know since my first thought was the above tests? Any functions in python/R are most welcome :)

Hope you have a nice day!

Comment: I think this is what you need: https://rdrr.io/cran/tsqn/man/GPH_estimate.html?msclkid=8d610294aadb11ecb84548d7cc2f7251